# Pandas - Dropping multiple empty columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have some tables where the first 11 columns are populated with data, but all columns after this are blank. I tried:

```
df=df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

which didn't work. I then used:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[range(11,36)], axis=1)
```

Which worked on the first few tables, but then some of the tables were longer or shorter and so this generated error messages.

How can I either drop completely empty columns or delete all columns bar the first 11?

Comment: When you say empty do we mean blank strings or `NaN` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just subscript the columns:

```
df = df[df.columns[:11]]
```

This will return just the first 11 columns

or you can do:

```
df.drop(df.columns[11:], axis=1)
```

To drop all the columns after the 11th one.